# Why does Sonarqube claim that a variable can be null or undefined if these checks are made (JS)?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I've run into the following problem that has been bugging me.

```
const dataCleaned =
    typeof data !== 'undefined' && data 
      ? { 
            positions: data.map((e) => {...}),
            ...
        } : [];
```

And SonarQube complains about the line: `positions: data.map((e) => {...}` with the following Bug Message:

```
TypeError can be thrown as "data" might be null or undefined here.
```

Is this an issue with SonarQube, or am I missing something and `data` can really be undefined or null?

Comment: Given that undefined is false-y you don't need both those checks. It also seems odd that in one case you get an object and in the other it's an array. But SonarQube is wrong that data could be undefined in that case.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. I'm using the 'data' (an array) to build an object here. Maybe my choice of variable names was not good here (I changed them from the original). Please consider adding your reply as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I meant that you have `name = condition ? { /* an object */ } : [ /* an array */ ]`. That likely makes it more complicated to deal with further on in your program.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right, I missed that. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the solution did you get @seveneights ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this type of issue, Here **{}** are not acting as an object rather a new JavaScript statement due to which the above condition is not valid.
To fix this try like this

```
var posistion = null;
if(data !== 'undefined' && data !== null){
  posistion =  data.map((e) => {...})
}
const dataCleaned = posistion ? {
          positions: posistion,
          ...
        } : [];
```

Here you have to focus on both **undefined** & **null** check of the `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with sonar report, even if over the variable is applied a check for null or undefined, sonarqube detects it as an error. For example:

```
if (varName!== undefined && varName!== null) {
     secondVariable= varName.propertyName;
}
```

Sonar reports:
"TypeError can be thrown as "varName" might be null or undefined here."
It seems like a bug in sonarqube.